# Защита cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Заметил большую дыру в безопасности своего сайта (благо пока работает локально). В куки, после авторизации пользователя, записывается его id (в не шифрованном виде, то есть $_COOKIE['id'] = 1), далее по этой куке вытаскивается различная информация из бд для этого пользователя и т.д. Если подменить номер этой куки в браузере, скажем с 1 на 2, то вуаля, мы авторизованы под пользователем с id 2 :D Вот хочу спросить, как защитить эту куку, можно конечно зашифровать её, но есть ли другие способы проверки, например соответствие куки ip или что то в этом роде?

Comment: Ни как не надо их защищать, в куке надо хранить шифрованые данные авторизации, все остальное - сессия на сервере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая дыра заделывается с помощью специального хеша в базе данных для каждого пользователя.

```
$хеш = md5(user_agent . '%' .  user_password)
```

При авторизации на сайте генерируем этот хеш и записываем в базу данных, в cookies записываем id пользователя, при посещении сайта каждый раз генерируем новый хеш и сверяем с тем который хранится в базе данных.

При поставлении другого id, хеш будет неверный и пользователь будет разлогинен.

И не нужно никакие id хешировать!

Comment: понял, частично... то есть залогинился, сгенерировали, записали... а дальше? каждый раз проверять id на совпадение с записью в БД, эт получается нужно ко всем страницам сайта подключить эту проверку на id, правильно?

Comment: Да, правильно.

Comment: а если тот же человек зашел с 2 разных браузеров сразу (ну мало ли), получится что опять несовпадение и постоянно его будет кидать на страницу логина, ибо в базе для него 2 хэша а сравнивается он с первой записью в БД (почему то, а не проходит по всем), тоесть хэш второго браузера в БД к примеру 12345, а для первого браузера хэш 54321, вот и сравнивает всегда 12345=54321

Comment: Все правильно, работайте с одного браузера. Это безопасность.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, хранить любые данные на клиенте надо зашифрованными. Во-вторых, Данные об авторизации лучше хранить в сессии. В-тртьих, хранить лучше не id, а хэш(вышеупомянутый md5, sha1 или их комбинация) от логина+пароля+юзерагента+мусора aka соли. И авторизовывать юзера на каждом запросе.

Пример можете посмотреть в коде любой CMS, где есть авторизация, да и просто в инете много их.

Comment: Если кто-то боится перебора пароля - сделайте sha512 xDDD

Answer (score 1):

куки и IP - ИМХО не лучший вариант, т.к. IP у меня меняется раз в час, т.е. мне постоянно нужно будет проходить авторизацию.

Сделай лучше так.

Куку пользователю

```
$_COOKIE['id'] = md5(id+email); // бонально, но можно и просто id юзера.
```

Далее когда он авторизуется в БД в какую-нить таблицу можно записать соль авторизации (вожно помнить пользователь может зайти с 1,2 и 10 машин, работа, дом, подруга, друг и там может не нажать "ВЫХОД с сайта")  для этого нужно хранить эту "соль" постоянно как в гугле кто видел, там можно посмотреть с какие IP открыт аккаунт, и потом если что удалить все.

Так вот, записываешь эту "соль" вида? можно добавить и время и дату, что выгоднее и лучше, я просто суть пишу.

```
$rnd="1243dfrwe@"; // допустим при регистрации юзеру в поле записывается определенная соль для дальнейших проверок
md5(id+ip+email+$rnd) // допустим
// так же ему куку с этой "солью" для проверки +$rnd эту штуку
```

Ну и при входе узера с этого IP проверяешь куку и то что в БД лежит, подходит авторизуешь, не подходит говоришь ему пусть залогинится.

Если коряво написал не обессутьте.

Answer (score 0):

Есть элементарные правила безопасности в PHP. Их должны соблюдать все веб-разработчики, пишущие на PHP. В кукисах вся инфа должна хранится в какой-нибудь кодировке, например, MD5. В PHP для этого даже есть функция - md5();

Comment: Бывалые, конечно, не узнают md5(1) =)

Comment: да это понятно, просто смотрел на многих сайтах там мой id пользователя хранится в открытом виде в куки, ну и тоже так сделал...

Comment: На тех многих сайтах можно получить доступ к любому аккаунту. Попробуйте =)

Comment: У меня на сайте чистый id хранится - взломайте, печеньку дам :D

Comment: ВК например, там id явно указан в куки)... а что если сохранять id пользователя в сессию, ну и проверить: if($_SESSION['id'] != $_COOKIE['id']){$_COOKIE['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];}

Comment: Мне сложно так судить, в чем допущены пробелы. Я никогда ниче не зашифровывал, тк смотреть на эту шифровку уж очень не приятно, да и на всеми любимом контакте шифровки помоему не стоит!! Попробуйте создать проверку на странице. Вобщем добавьтесь в скайп а то тут очень напряжно) bloodlordy

Comment: > ВК например, там id явно указан в куки

FALSE, как кука называется?)

Да не хранится id в куках у вконтакта, вы думаете Дуров наркоман совсем?

Comment: ну там есть кука "l" в качестве содержимого куки, мой id)

Comment: @Sh4dow ахаха, у меня на всех сайтах хранится в куках только id. Попробуй взломай!

Comment: @dikardRus ага, а еще есть кука p с хэшем пароля, который вы хрен поломаете. Имелось в виду, что авторизовывают точно не только по ней. Плюс там еще есть хэш сессии remixsid, и без этих трех кук вы точно не выторизуетесь.

Comment: @Sh4dow бред полный, для авторизации нужна одна кука `remixsid`.

Comment: @uWeb куки l и p доступны только для login.vk.com. Ну мне влом было писать "для авторизации на всех сервисах, имеющих отношение к вконтакту") Плюс я не  уверен, но мобыть еще как вспомогательные а ля автокомплит основной формы.

Comment: @Sh4dow ничего не понял, но у меня авторизация через `curl` на login.vk.com (другой и нет) идет с помощью одной куки `remixsid`.

Answer (score 0):

У себя на сайте я сделал так :

1. У каждого пользователя есть логин, пароль и ид.
2. После авторизации генерируется 3 случайных числа + конкатенация строк логин, пароль, ид, ай пи и всё это переводится в md5().
3. Получившаяся строка является уникальной и записывается в таблицу с сессиями, а так же передаётся юзеру в куки.
4. Куки, которые нам прислал юзер мы чистим регуляркой от лишних символов, оставляем только [a-zA-Z0-9].
5. Проверяем длину куки с сессией, строка в md5 всегда будет длиной 32 символа, а после уже ищем в базе данных, в таблице с сессиями, есть ли запись с таким идентификатором сессии и ай пи адресом, тоесть вот так : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sessions WHERE sessid='$cookie_session' AND ip='$ip', если кол-во записей равно 1 - авторизован, иначе - нет.

Answer (score -1):

Я генеририрую уникальный ключ, который кладу в бд. А потом по этому ключу заполняю сессию.

```
<?php
    /* Если существует кука автовхода */
    if(!empty($_COOKIE['autokey'])){
        $sql = "SELECT a.`autokey`, a.`user_id`, u.* FROM `autokey` a, `users` u WHERE a.autokey = '".clear($_COOKIE['autokey']."' AND a.`user_id` = u.`user_id`");
        if($row = $db->fetchrow($sql)){
            foreach($row as $k=>$v){
                $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
            }
            $auto = autokeygenerate($_SESSION['user_name']);
            setcookie('autokey', $auto, 604800);
            $db->query("DELETE FROM `autokey` WHERE `user_id` = ".$_SESSION['user_id']);
            $db->query("INSERT INTO `autokey` (`autokey` ,`user_id` ,`key_time`)  VALUES ('{$auto}', '{$_SESSION['user_id']}', '" . (time()+604800) . "')");
            header("Location: index.php");
            $_SESSION['start']  = true;
        }   }
        if($_POST){
            /* Если не вошли по автовходу, то входим по данным присланным с формы */
             $r_login = clear($_POST['login']);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = '". clear($_POST['login'] ."' AND `user_pass` = '". md5($_POST['pass'])."'");
            if($row = $db->fetchrow($sql)){
                foreach($row as $k=>$v){
                    $_SESSION[$k] = $v;
                }
                $auto = autokeygenerate($_SESSION['user_name']);
                $db->query("DELETE FROM `autokey` WHERE `user_id` = ".$_SESSION['user_id']);
                    if(!empty($_POST['autologin'])){
                $db->query("INSERT INTO `autokey` (`autokey` ,`user_id` ,`key_time`)  VALUES ('{$auto}', '{$_SESSION['user_id']}', '" . (time() + 608400) . "')");
                    setcookie('autokey', $auto);
                    }
                header("Location: index.php");
                $_SESSION['start']  = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $r_login = false;
        }
    $sm->assign(array(
    'requestlogin'      =>    $r_login,

    ));
    $sm->display('/user/login_t.tpl');
```